Formatting not being applied to Django form in iOS Safari
This the html code which is producing a 'search bar' for the user to input text:
<form id="searchForm" method="GET" action="{% url 'search_mountains' %}#search-and-grid">
  {{ form.as_p }}
</form>

The formatting is declared in the associated CSS:
#searchForm input[type="text"] {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    color: #303030;
    display: inline-block; 
    border: #07A3B2 solid 1.75px;
    padding-left: 7px;
    font-size: 0.65em;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.9;
    width: 150px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-user-select: text; /* Chrome, Opera, Safari */
    -moz-user-select: text; /* Firefox 2+ */
    -ms-user-select: text; /* IE 10+ */
    user-select: text; /* Standard syntax */
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}

Which produces the expected result:

This formatting is being applied on desktop versions both locally and when deployed in AWS elastic beanstalk and works fine when working locally, even for iOS safari, however when accessing the deployed website in iOS safari the formatting is not being applied:

This is only happening when loading the website in 'production' in iOS Safari, it works fine in Google Chrome for iOS for instance.
I've tried changing the html syntax to a direct  tag rather than a Django input but the same result persists.

The problem is not with AWS, but with safari, as safari automatically adds some classes to different inputs, so you need to treat this classes in your css.
I recommend that you debug your code in safari to see which class is being added to your input. There's some sites that allow you to debug in safari using windows and others navigators.

For instance, It is needed to insert this css to left-align text in date inputs in safari: input::-webkit-date-and-time-value {   text-align: left; }
